# How to set an ItemClickListener for an item inside the list view with custom adapter?

Tags: java, android

I have a list view with custom adapter (simple adapter) for example, by this code: `androidListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);` So, i have an image view and want to make an click listener but i have a listview click listener. I wrote this code:

```
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + listViewnumber));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

but it isn't working, any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Where have you put that code? In your CustomAdapter Class?

Try to do something like that:

**SearchActivity.java**

```
        final ListView result_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.result_list_view);
    final ResultsListCustomAdapter adapter = new ResultsListCustomAdapter(this);
    result_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**ResultListCustomAdapter.java**:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final SearchResultViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new SearchResultViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_results_list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.wordTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Result_TextView);

        viewHolder.addToFavsImgButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_to_favs_button);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (SearchResultViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.wordTextView.setText(results.get(position));

    viewHolder.wordTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent play_activity_intent = new Intent(context, PlayActivity.class);

    //Pulsante FAV
    viewHolder.addToFavsImgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utility.addFavs(context, viewHolder.wordTextView.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: The rule is the same.
Let's say this is your Simple Adapter
    `SimpleAdapter adapter =new SimpleAdapter (this, val1, R.layout.mytask, new String[]{"a","c","b"}, new int[]{R.id.View1,R.id.View2,R.id.ViewStatus})
        {
            @Override
            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

//Override your button here
return v;
}`

Haven't tested the code, which is not mine, but I did this before. Let me know and we'll get through this.

Let me know.

Comment: Okay, i will try it tomorrow since i will sleep now